# Mongodb 16 MB document example, how much actual data?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

Does anyone have a practical downloadable/viewable example of a 16mb (max size) mongodb doucument?

Should be alot of data but im trying to get the feel and understanding how much data can you store in a 16 mb document,
like *"How many sql rows of a 10 column table would that be"* sort of question

Thanks

Comment: _"... Should be alot of data..."_ - I think about 700 to 800 pages (as in a book)  of text

Comment: See https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-source-data or google for "open data json", you should find a lot.

Comment: Thank you! , ill answer the question, the coronavirus json is really useful in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the size of various documents using the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html).

For example, a document `{a:1}` consisting of one key with an integer value would take 5+1+2+4=12 bytes.

You can use various drivers to convert your data to BSON to see how much space it actually takes up:

```rb
serene% irb -rbson
irb(main):001:0> {a:1}.to_bson.to_s
=> "\f\x00\x00\x00\x10a\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00"
irb(main):002:0> {a:1}.to_bson.to_s.length
=> 12
```

If you have, let's say, documents which are flat (non-nested) mappings with keys that are 10 bytes long and 64-bit integer values, each key-value pair takes up 1+10+1+8=20 bytes. You can have about 800,000 such key-value pairs in a single document.

Answer (score -1):

As Wernfried Domscheit said, https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-source-data provides a json with alot of data to view and test with

I suggest to import the data into MongoDB compass to view all the documents clearly.