# How will the size of MongoDB database increase after adding more data?

Tags: mongodb, size

I am trying to calculate the increase in the size of the database after adding more data. The data I want to add is a list of 512 float values. And there are 750,000 documents in the collection. I'd like to add such a list to each of the documents.

So far, [I have found][1] that MongoDB stores data in BSON files, which can hold 16MB. One float value takes 64 bits. So, 16MB can keep 2,000,000 float values. It is, therefore, impossible to add such a list to each of the documents.

Am I correct in my calculations? Or does it work differently?
Thanks in advance for any help!

[1]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682714/does-mongodb-support-floating-point-types#:~:text=MongoDB%20stores%20data%20in%20a,bit%20IEEE%20754%20floating%20point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682714/does-mongodb-support-floating-point-types#:%7E:text=MongoDB%20stores%20data%20in%20a,bit%20IEEE%20754%20floating%20point))

Comment: Not clear what you mean. 512 values is far below 2'000'000 values, so what is the problem? **One** BSON document can have a max size of 16 MB, however the number of documents is only limited by your disk space.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit But 512 values for each of the 750'000 documents is much more than 2million values

Comment: And also, do I understand correctly that one BSON represents one collection? Or there might be several files for one collection?

Comment: 512 values times 64 Bit gives 32kBit = 4kByte. The max. size **of EACH** document is 16 MByte, so what is your problem?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Oh, so BSON stores one document, not the whole collection? Then there is no problem at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document size limit applies to each document in the collection, not to the collection overall.

Separately, MongoDB stores at least the type byte with each value, such that doubles practically take 9 bytes minimum (if they are in an array) + the key name converted to string with a null terminator. See http://bsonspec.org/spec.html.

See also [Mongodb 16 MB document example, how much actual data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635245/mongodb-16-mb-document-example-how-much-actual-data/66639829#66639829)

Comment: So, the limit of 16MB is about one document, not the whole collection? That really simplifies everything. Thank you!